# Using PlayerPrefs (unity)

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have recently been creating a game with tutorials. Unfortunately, they didn't cover a save score feature. Thanks to another user, I was able to figure out that I needed to use playerprefs. I watched tutorials online, but none of them were helpful. If you can, please help me!

Gold Per Sec Script:

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;

 public class GoldPerSec : MonoBehaviour {

     public UnityEngine.UI.Text gpsDisplay;
     public Click click;
     public ItemManager[] items;

     void Start () {
         StartCoroutine(AutoTick ());
     }

     void Update () {
         gpsDisplay.text = GetGoldPerSec() + " Money Per Sec";
     }

     public float GetGoldPerSec() {
         float tick = 0;
         foreach (ItemManager item in items) {
             tick += item.count * item.tickValue;
         }
         return tick;   
     }

     public void AutoGoldPerSec() {
         click.gold += GetGoldPerSec() / 10;
     }

     IEnumerator AutoTick() {
         while (true) {
             AutoGoldPerSec();
             yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.10f);
         }
     }
 }
```

Gold Per Click script:

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;

 public class Click : MonoBehaviour {

     public UnityEngine.UI.Text gpc;
     public UnityEngine.UI.Text goldDisplay;
     public float gold = 0.00f;
     public int goldperclick = 1;

     void Update () {
         goldDisplay.text = "" + gold.ToString("F0");
         gpc.text = "Money Per Click: " + goldperclick;
     }

     public void Clicked(){
         gold += goldperclick;
     }

 }
```

My idea was for the game to save when the game is quit, and load as soon as you load the game back up. I am a complete beginner, if anyone can tell me how to do this, please tell me! Thanks! :D

Comment: What value do you want to save?

Comment: I want to save the game when it is quit, and load it back once open

Comment: you can save state of game (values of certain variables). In your case it can be value of gold. Check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that PlayerPrefs is an easy way to save data but also an very unsafe way. The player can easily manipulate his "goldValue" since it's just stored as an integer in some file on his device. PlayerPrefs should usually just be used for values the player can changed any way within in game, like volume setting etc.

EXAMPLE CODE

```
  void Save()
 {
     string filename = "/filename.dat";
     BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
     FileStream file = File.Create(Application.persistentDataPath+filename);
     bf.Serialize(file, goldValue); //Use can easily use e.g. a List if you want to store more date
     file.Close();
 }

  bool Load()
 {
     string filename = "/filename.dat";
     if (File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + filename))
     {
         BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
         FileStream file = File.Open(Application.persistentDataPath + filename, FileMode.Open);
         goldValue=(int) bf.Deserialize(file); 
         file.Close();
         return true;
     }
     return false;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I managed to figure out. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

You can use unity's existing functions to achieve this.

For saving data use unity's OnApplicationQuit function like this

```
void OnApplicationQuit() {
    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("key", value);
}
```

And for Restoring the values use unity's Awake function like this

```
void Awake(){
    value = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("key");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code to `Click` class:

```
void Awake()
{
    LoadData();
}

void OnApplicationQuit() 
{
    SaveData();
}

void SaveData()
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("gold",gold);
}

void LoadData()
{
    gold = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("gold",0f);
}
```