# Unity How to save high score for each specific level?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, user-interface

I have been using unity on and off for a year and still learning. I am trying to create a basic game where a player has to go through levels and collecting points under a time countdown on android. The player will have completed the level once it has hit an endtrigger which would display the amount of points collected along with the time taken to complete it. The high score will then be displayed from the multiplication of the points and time taken, which is simple.

The high score would have already been saved using playerprefs and the high score will then be displayed on the level select screen below each level (ex. lvl 1: 136, lvl2: 245, etc...). I have just learned how to save a simple int using playerprefs.

My problem is, how do I save the high score of each individual level and then display it in the level select screen using playerprefs.

Comment: PlayerPrefs uses key-value pairs. Just use the level name as the key and your score as the value.

Comment: sorry I am very new to this, how do I do that? is there an example?

Comment: @CodingNeeded one example how to find this out would be starting with a google search like "how to use playerprefs unity" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39015560/using-playerprefs-unity

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using PlayerPrefs (unity)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39015560/using-playerprefs-unity)

Comment: thanks for the reply, but unfortunately no

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in my first comment - PlayerPrefs works with key-value pairs so you can do it like this.

```
// Setting values
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Level1", 100);
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Level2", 200);

// Getting values
int someint = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Level1");
int someint2 = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Level2");
```

So when you want to save it for each level you do something like this.

```
 //Save Score with scene name as the key and the score as the value
 PlayerPrefs.SetInt(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name, _score);
```

You can put it anywhere you want. It will always get the name of the currently active scene as the key.

You can also save floats and strings and also delete entries.

For more information take a look at the Unity docs:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html

Comment: I see your logic here, and I have been trying to utilise this, the problem is I dont know how to use it. how do I save this as level 1 high score, cause I have one script where it saves the value as just 'highscore' only, so how do i save it for just the level 1 scene? and when I reach level 2 how do I save it for the level 2 scene only? do i have to keep making each script for it? cause I would like to make many more levels

Comment: I updated my answer and included the way to get the Scene name and use it in PlayerPrefs. This is the simplest way to do it. At this point, this is literally spoonfeeding. If you still have issues understanding it, please consider learning Unity a little more and share your code. So we can help you out better.

Comment: haha sorry and thank you so much, this worked for me. thank you for having the patience to show me how its done. I will learn and understand unity better